# Designing the safest possible, futuristic combat helmet

Tags: science-based, armors

To protect against blunt strikes, high velocity projectiles, and concussive energy weapons, what type of helmet design would best distribute force of impact and/or redirect blows away from the head?

Comment: Simple answer: make things slide off. Lots of curves, facing away from the neck and eyes. After that, it depends on what you're defending against.

Comment: Is stealth/camo a concern?

Comment: That could be a consideration. I'm most concerned with impact deflection.

Comment: There are so many balances that have to be taken into account. The "safest possible" to the given parameters is probably one in which the person can't see out of. When looking at past helmets (that also protect the face), the thing that seems to change the most are how to protect the eyes while being able to see.

Comment: Other considerations are communication (whether you need to leave the mouth and ears open) and how much neck movement you'd need - because if you take a heavy hit and your neck breaks whats the point of protecting your skull to that incredible impact?

Comment: If communication were handled through a built-in electronic system and a well-designed visor accounted for visibility and eye protection, would that suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common futuristic helmet is a sphere, or ovoid helmet.  The reason is that a sphere is the strongest shape to resist pressure and impacts - there's a reason most helmets are half-circles, and it's actually for the same reason our *heads* are close to spherical.  That's just the best shape to protect your brain, and helmets - even high tech ones - operate on similar principles.

One problem with spheres though is that they absolutely suck at hiding you, because no matter how you're oriented one part of the sphere will reflect perfectly back at any radar transmitter.  Instead, consider the shape of the stealth fighter:

[image: Stealth fighter]

The hard angles negate almost all radar reflections, because incoming radiation will be absorbed or reflected away from the transmitter unless it happens to line up exactly with one of the flat surfaces.

In the future, I expect that stealth is going to be extremely important, even for foot soldiers.  Being pinpointed will kill you, and you don't want to have a helmet that's easy to see on radar.

So I suggest a three-layered mix (or four, depending on how you count):

1. The outer layer will be an angular, radar-absorbent material.  Along with properly designed armor, it will keep your soldiers from being detected as long as it's not compromised.  This layer will be tough, but it's shape will prevent it from being extremely useful against bullets.
2. The inner hard layer will be an almost perfect sphere, to offer the maximum protection against the skull.  Likely this should actually have several layers itself, comprising of fabrics like Kevlar and ceramic/metal plates.
3. In between these two layers will be an impact absorbing [crumple zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crumple_zone).  This is a layer that will protect against blunt objects and concussive blasts, by taking the damage from the impact itself.  Basically it's designed to fail in such a way that a minimum amount of energy gets through to the user.
4. Inside the inner hard layer and against the user's head will be additional padding and concussive-reducing materials, as a final barrier to protect the skull and brain.

This provides a balance - you get excellent stealth until you get hit, but when you *are* hit you still have a good chance of surviving the strike.

Comment: Would it be too bulky to deal with neck mobility, like DoubleDouble mentioned above?

Comment: If radar weren't an issue--maybe the suit emits some kind of interference--it sounds like the outside could look like whatever you wanted it to, as long as the inner layer is spherical.

Comment: @JacobJones: It would need to be part of a suit that integrates and helps lock it into place, otherwise the stealth characteristics are useless (since your armor/clothes will have a bigger signature).  One possibility is that you "see" through cameras, using some sort of HUD or internal display.  That would make it more complicated, though, because if it fails you'd need to allow some way for the person to remove the front and regain vision.

Answer (score 3):

A critical component would be a shock-activated mechanism which locks the helmet in place with respect to the torso. Letting the head *move* under impact lets the brain bounce around inside the skull. The resulting non-penetrating TBI (Traumatic Brain Injury) is a major consequence of IEDs and traffic accidents.

Comment: +1 : Locking the helment to the torso during impact will definitely reduce neck and spinal injuries.  Any impact strong enough to move both head and body might still result in TBI if the blast-accelerated soldier stops suddenly by hitting a wall.

Comment: How about a shifting mass to act as an inertial damper?

Comment: How strong do you think a soldier's neck muscles are, to support the extra weight?

Answer (score 1):

Since the helmet is futuristic, we can assume it has some ultra-hard alloy shell that is remarkably hard to break through.  This removes the "sharp" injury issues such as bullet holes, knife wounds, and broken skulls.

However, there is one thing armor like that cannot stop: physics.  When there is a collision, momentum must be conserved.  We have to either deflect the oncomming assault, or soak up its momentum.  For a bullet this is a minor concern (maybe a bigger concern for large bullets like a .50cal).  However, for things like a baseball bat, they are major concerns.  If the skull moves faster than the brain can catch up, its concussion city.

To solve this, the helmet is going to have active and reactive features.  The outer skin should include a set of robot arm like devices.  When a slow enough projectile (like a baseball bat) comes into view, these arms reach out from the helmet and try to deflect the blow.  The effect would be like having a karate master guarding your head.  In cases where the deflection cannot be perfect, it can cushion the blow like the foam in a bicycle helmet, except the restraining action of the arms would act like foam on the outside.

Of course, this wont protect against everything, so the helmet needs to come with a set of reactive features as well.  One reactive feature would be what WhatRoughBeat suggested: a way to lock the skull to the torso, ensuring there aren't any neck injuries.  We also need a very exotic reactive measure: explosives.  This helmet does amazing things against slow projectiles, but fast projectiles are too hard to stop, so their momentum has to be dealt with.  Likewise, explosive concussions could still cause a brain concussion if they threw the person back too quickly.  When one of these situations occurs, the helmet needs to fire off squibs that are designed to act like small propulsive devises, rapidly undoing the momentum transfer of a bullet or a concussive blast by transferring the momentum to the air behind the person.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a page from tanks and AFV's, the soldier might be protected from many sorts of threats by an active defense system, which fires some sort of counter round against the incoming threat.

Consider that Israel now offers a "Mini-Spike" Anti personnel guided missile. Soldiers will face a threat from incoming rounds which can be guided right to impact. A missile sized weapon could be countered by a grenade sized counter weapon that causes it to tumble out of control before impact (and ideally disrupts the warhead). If the soldier is "painted" by a laser pointer, the detector launches a smoke grenade which blocks the laser and interrupts the beam path, throwing off the sensor. A more advanced solution might be to include some sort of metallic element as well, to scatter millimetric wave radar.

Concussion and blast *could* theoretically be disrupted before reaching the soldier as well, either by throwing out a shock wave that intersects the incoming one, or using some mechanical means of disrupting or deflecting the shockwave. Boeing has applied for a patent on a system which uses highly focused microwaves to create the cancellation wave.

Active armour is obviously going to be more complex than passive armour (the soldier will need a backpack housing the sensors and launching tubes for the grenades, as a minimum), and the tactics will also change to keep soldiers from hitting each other with their protective shields.